# How to distribute an array accoding to specific conditions in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, google-apps-script

I'm trying to organize an array I have according to certain conditions that must be met.

I have 3 kinds of arrays:
Array of people

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

Array of dates

```
var array2 = ["date1","date2","date3","date4"]
```

For each value in array2, I have corresponding separate arrays (or 2D arrays, don't know what's best to be honest)

```
var date1Group1 = [1,6,7,8]
var date1Group2 = [4,5,9]
var date1Group3 = [6,17,15,3,11]
```

OR

```
var date1Groups = [[1,6,7,8],[4,5,9],[6,17,15,3,11]]
```

Each date has their own corresponding group arrays

```
var date2Groups = [...]
...
var date4Groups = [...]
```

What I need to do is to distribute proportionately the values of array1 into a new array corresponding to having it split by array2.length. In this particular case since:

```
array1.length = 18
array2.length = 4
```

I can have for example 1 2D array of 2 sub-arrays of 5 values and 2 sub-arrays of 4 values, OR 4 separate arrays for each group:

```
var arrayResultDate = [[v1,v2,v3,v4,v5],[v1,v2,v3,v4,v5],[v1,v2,v3,v4],[v1,v2,v3,v4]]
```

OR

```
var arrayResultDate1 = [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5]
var arrayResultDate2 = [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5]
var arrayResultDate3 = [v1,v2,v3,v4]
var arrayResultDate4 = [v1,v2,v3,v4]
```

In order to distribute them, I need to check that the values asigned to each of these new arrays, are not repeated in a same group of it's corresponding date. For example:

```
//This is valid be because no value is repeated in any of the groups for date1
arrayResultDate1 = [2,4,7,14,18]

//This is NOT VALID because values 6 and 8 are in date1Group1 / date1Groups[0]
arrayResultDate1 = [3,6,8,18,12]
```

What I wanted to do was first asigning from array1[0] to array1[3], to arrayResultDate1 to arrayResultDate4 (1 each)

```
arrayResultDate1.push(array1[0])
arrayResultDate2.push(array1[1])
arrayResultDate3.push(array1[2])
arrayResultDate4.push(array1[3])
```

OR

```
arrayResultDate[0].push(array1[0])
arrayResultDate[1].push(array1[1])
arrayResultDate[2].push(array1[2])
arrayResultDate[3].push(array1[3])
```

Then use loops to go through the rest of the values in array1, and check if the criteria is met in each resulting array. Asing to the array if conditions are met or go for the next one if it doesn't.

**Conditions:**
If trying to asign **array1[x]** to **arrayResultDate1**, check if **value array1[x] **AND** values already in arrayResultDate1**, are at the same time in any of the groups for **date1**:

```
date1Group1 = [1,6,7,8]
date1Group2 = [4,5,9]
date1Group3 = [6,17,15,3,11]
```

If said values **ARE NOT** at the same time in **any of the groups**, then

```
arrayResultDate1.push(array1[x])
```

If the values **ARE** in at least one of the groups, then continue with the next resulting array and check with it's corresponding groups (in this case it would be **arrayResultDate2** so **date2Group1, date2Group2**, etc.)

I wasn't able to organize the code properly due to the loops inside other loops that I assume are needed. I hope this is a bit more clear. Please let me know if it's still not.

Comment: @doubleunary The groups are per date. The groups provided are  for "date1" only. Having said that, Sergio It would help if you provide all the groups for each date. Provide as a [mcve], input and expected output for the input.

Comment: @doubleunary and TheMaster. Thank you for your replies. I've made some changes to my question. I hope this is a bit more clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Comment: Maybe it's just residual dizziness from standing up too fast, but I'm not making much sense of this on a casual reading.  It's not horrible, but you're telling us more about *how* to do what you want than about *what* you actually want.  One suggestion: don't say "I want A, or maybe B."  Make a decision.  And compactly give an example of your input with the corresponding output you're looking for.  Explain anything not clear about the relationship between input and output, but focus more on what data goes where and not how someone might implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` and `Array.sort()`, like this:

```js
function test() {
  const people = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,];
  const criteria = [
    { label: 'date1', mutuallyExclusive: [[1, 6, 7, 8,], [4, 5, 9,], [6, 17, 15, 3, 11,],], },
    { label: 'date2', mutuallyExclusive: [[1, 6,],], },
    { label: 'date3', mutuallyExclusive: [[1, 7,],], },
    { label: 'date4', mutuallyExclusive: [[1, 8,],], },
  ];
  const assignments = distributeObjectsToGroups(people, criteria);
  console.log(assignments);
}


/**
* Distributes objects to groups observing multiple mutual exclusivity criteria.
*
* Processes each object in turn in the order they appear in the objects array.
* Attempts to make result groups approximately equal size by placing each object
* in the currently smallest group.
* Puts objects that do not fit in any group in an 'unassigned' group.
*
* @param {Object[]} objects The objects to place into groups, as in [1, 2, 3, 4,].
* @param {Object[]} groups An array of group labels and mutual exclusivity criteria.
*                   Each criteria is a 2D array that lists objects that should be 
*                   mutually exclusive and not appear in the same result group.
*                   [
*                     { label: 'date1', mutuallyExclusive: [[1, 2, 3,], [2, 4,]], },
*                     { label: 'date2', mutuallyExclusive: [[2, 3,],], },
*                   ]
* @return {Object}  The group labels and objects placed in each group.
*                   { date1: [1, 4,], date2: [2,], unassigned: [3,], }
*/
function distributeObjectsToGroups(objects, groups) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 3 November 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74294212/13045193
  const result = { unassigned: [], };
  groups.forEach(group => result[group.label] = []);
  objects.forEach(object => {
    const suitable = groups
      .filter(group =>
        !group.mutuallyExclusive.some(exclude =>
          exclude.includes(object) &&
          result[group.label].some(object2 => exclude.includes(object2)))
      )
      .sort((a, b) => result[a.label].length - result[b.label].length);
    if (suitable.length) {
      result[suitable[0].label].push(object);
      return;
    }
    result.unassigned.push(object);
  });
  return result;
}
```

A test run logs this:

```
{
  date1: [1, 5, 10, 13, 17],
  date2: [2, 6, 9, 14, 18],
  date3: [3, 7, 11, 15],
  date4: [4, 8, 12, 16],
  unassigned: [],
}
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thank you @doublenary ! Wow! I would've definitely never been able to do that with my knowledge haha just one question, is there a way to set a max number of assigned values for each date? Using more accurate criteria where I have 20 values in people, more restrictions, and the same 4 dates, I get:

date1=[1.0, 6.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 20.0]
date2=[2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 14.0, 18.0]
date3=[3.0, 7.0, 11.0, 15.0, 19.0]
date4=[4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0]

Would it be possible to set for example in that case a max number of 5 values per date?

Comment: Nevermind! I found a code to shuffle [people] eveytime before running your script and haven't had any issues again. I don't mind If I need to run It a couple of times If it ever happens in the future. Thank you again!